# Confusion matrix generates a and b as labels but not what I need

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-mining

I have a bin and my label should be 'points' but when I generate the confusion matrix, it generates something known as a and b as labels but it doesn't show the labels as points above 90 and points below 90 which is as per my bins. Here is my code.

```
print(y_test.values)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test.values, preds)
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                      normalize=False,
                      title='Confusion matrix',
                      cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
"""
This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
"""
if normalize:
    cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    print("Normalized confusion matrix")
else:
    print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

print(cm)

plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
plt.title(title)
plt.colorbar()
tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
thresh = cm.max() / 2.
for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
    plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
             horizontalalignment="center",
             color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
plt.figure()
plot_confusion_matrix(cm)
plt.show()
```

And here is my graph, which shows a and b instead of points below and points above
[image]

Comment: You might be passing a and b to xticks. https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html # set the locations and labels of the xticks
xticks( arange(5), ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Sally', 'Sue') )

Comment: @ArunJoyThekkiniyath, just in case if I don't want to pass in the labels, is there a way to automatically tell the model to fetch it ?

Comment: labels is an optional field, just don't pass that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working through the model I observed few thing which I believe is the best approach for this question. Maybe someone would find this helpful so I just wanted to clear this question.

> I had created a bin from one label, so the label was **points** and the
>   bins I created was **'points above 90' and 'points below 90'** so these
>   were the labels for the graph which had to show the value instead of
>   **'a' and 'b'**. In the above case I had balanced the data well during
>   bin's creation.

Hence, I changed my code to get the **plot of my confusion matrix** like below

```
 plt.tight_layout()
 plt.ylabel('True label')
 plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
 plt.figure()
 plot_confusion_matrix(cm,['points above 90', 'points below 90'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think [Chetan Vasudevan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7923124/chetan-vasudevan)'s answer is what you're looking for. It's straightforward. 
However, in case you're still using this function, and there's a high chance that you still are, I just wanted to add that the new implementation by Sklearn, which uses `y_true`, `y_pred` instead of `cm`, needs specifically a `numpy` array. You cannot use a python lists for class labels anymore. Since I'm used to the old one, I've been struggling with the new one myself. Now the function's signature looks like this:

```
plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title=None,
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```

And I've been using the following the whole time:

```
plot_confusion_matrix(y_true=test_labels, y_pred=predictions, 
classes=['dog', 'cats'])
```

But it would return this **TypeError** saying:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

And what I'd like you to pay attention to, is that **`classes` must be a `numpy` array now**. If you'd like to understand why, look up the following line in the implementation:

```
classes = classes[unique_labels(y_true, y_pred)]
```